# Adduser: group sudo does not exist

Tags: sudo, adduser

I am able to login to my account but can't do anything related to superuser now.
Updates, sharing, sudo and all things say authentication failed.

I tried to correct that by going in recovery mode and adding my user to sudo but when i use adduser command, i get error message that group sudo does not exist

I searched for the error but could not get any link answering this :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output of `grep sudo /etc/group` command?

Comment: `sudo:x:27:manka,root`

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Fixed it by `addgroup sudo` as root, and then changing the Group ID to 201 in `/etc/groups`. (Pick an unused number < 1000)